# Accessibility for NSWindow displayed from agent on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility

NSWindow which is run as modal(runModalForWindow)from a launch agent which has NSUIElement set to 1( no dock icon or menu bar) is not accessible, Accessibility inspector is not displaying info for this window or button from that window.

We need this window to be accessible to automate it through AXElements,

Can we set some properties of Window or button to make it accessible( as per documentation they should be accessible). Are there any properties that we need to set, since this is launched from an agent without menu bar or dock item.

Thanks,
swetha

Answer (score 1):

The alert was shown from awakeFromNib which was causing issue, after moving the alert display code to applicationDidFinishLaunching, the alert is properly accessible through AXElements.